# What would be the best data structure to search and update integer values of an array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures, hashmap, binary-search, avl-tree

If I have the array as [7, 11, 13, 9, 4, 6], and the user input is 10

 I want the integer just above (or equal to ) 10 (in this case 11) and replace it with integer - 10 (11 - 10) 
I can't order the list and binary search as I have to return the index of updated element.
I looked into ordering the (index, integer) pairs and then binary searching but then after updating I have to re sort the array of pairs for next user input.

original array = [7, 11, 13, 9, 4, 6]
sorted array = [4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13]
user input = 10
output = 1 (index of updated integer)

updated sorted array = [4, 6, 7, 9, 1, 13]
re sorted array = [1, 4, 6, 7, 9, 13]
user input = 4
...

What data structure would be suitable to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **ordered set** to store (value, index) tuples. You can define custom comparison functions to fit your goal (it depends on the programming language in question).

Ordered set operations include:

1. Add an element.
2. Remove an element.
3. Search for an element.
4. Search for an element greater or equal than given element.
5. Search for an element greater than given element.

The given problem can be solved using an ordered set with operations as described above.

Some programming languages (like **set** in c++) have predefined data structures so you don't need to implement it from scratch (only to use it). Ordered set internal implementation usually is **Red-Black Tree** (c++) or **AVL Tree**.

Check if your programming language has a built-in ordered set or use some library that include it. It's a very useful and common data structure so it shouldn't be hard to find.